# What does mean by port is open and close on a server?

Tags: linux, ssh, port, server, server-configuration

I've got a reply from my server admin as **"Do you need any ports open?"**

On this server one website is hosted which is not getting loaded. So I conveyed him that the website is not getting loaded though I'm able to login to the given IP address through FTP client (File Zilla) and ssh (using terminal).

Actually I want to access the files at the said IP address through FTP client and its working fine. My main issue is that the website is not loading.

I'm not getting what does this question mean and what should I reply to it? I'm not aware of any such thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Services on the network use different "ports" to distinguish between different endpoints. You can imagine a port number as a "sub-address". For successful connection you need to know an IP address and also the port number.

For example FTP protocol uses port 21. You can find more detailed list of commonly used ports on Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

The common phrase "open some port" means the access to that particular port will be enabled on firewall (usually all ports are "closed" because of security).

**For your website you need ports 80 and 443 to be opened**

Comment: Are you saying that for FTP operations I need port 80 to be open  and for HTTP request processing I need port 443 to be open? If yes then it's fine but does this thing really relates to the issue I'm facing with loading the website? I don't think so. So what reply should I send to the server administrator? Please guide me.

Comment: FTP uses port 21. Port 80 is reserved for HTTP protocol (website) and port 443 is used for HTTPS (encrypted HTTP). In your case you probably only need port 80 to be opened.

Comment: Yes I got your point. My question is does that really relate to the issue in loading the website?

Answer (score 0):

If your website is using the HTTP protocol, then you need port 80 to be open. If it is using HTTPS protocol, then you need port 443 to be open.
Try getting both the ports opened, that should solve your problem immediately.